# Using Asynchronous context tracking in Remix app using Express as the server

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, remix.run

Using Remix with Express as the server, I want to create an Express middleware that creates an [async context](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html) so that all downstream functions (in particular everything in the "backend" Remix code) within the scope of a single request to have access to this context.

At the moment I'm doing:

```js
  // in my own custom ctx.ts

import { AsyncLocalStorage } from "node:async_hooks";

export const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage<string>();

export const createContext = (fn: any): any => {
  const trace = "hardcoded-trace (this would just be a new UUID or something)";
  return asyncLocalStorage.run(trace, fn);
};

export const getTrace = () => {
  return asyncLocalStorage.getStore();
};
```

```js
  // in server.ts

  const remixHandler = createRequestHandler({
          build: initialBuild,
          mode: initialBuild.mode,
        });

  app.use((req, res, next) => createContext(next));
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // hardcoded trace value is available here in a following middleware
    console.log(getTrace());
  });
  app.all("*", remixHandler);
```

```js
// in a Remix loader

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  // in the loader there is no access to the Trace (we seem to be out of the context here?)
  console.log(getTrace());
};
```

As best as I can tell; when Express hands over to Remix the async context is somehow lost. And it is not very clear how to dig deeper into this without doing a deep dive into the Remix internal behavior.

The only other way forward I can see is that in the `createRequestHandler` I pass the context into via the `getLoadContext`. And then create other seperate async contexts in the loader function, the action function, etc. This would seem like a very hacky implementation of what I want though. Essentially creating multiple contexts (plus context handover) for a single request (at least 3? Express, loader, action...).

My question is: how can I create a single async context and make it available throughout the Express middleware, Remix action, Remix loader, etc. so that I can have a cross cutting context from the point the Express request begins and ends?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but [their page about express adapter](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/other-api/adapter#creating-an-adapter) says that one should use `getLoadContext` from `createRequestHandler` to "bridge the gap between Remix and your server".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is what I referred to as the "hacky" approach in my original question (at least for my use case). Which is what I want to avoid having to do. But interesting that this is what they advocate. I think I'll do a little investigation into the Adapter for Express at this point to see what is going on.